# redirecting www to non-www leads to too many redirection

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have the following virtual config in my nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/smartpanel;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.test.com;
    return 301 http://test.com$request_uri;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    autoindex off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }


   include snippets/phpmyadmin.conf;
}
```

I basically wanted to redirect all www to non www, however what the config above just give me a back and forth redirection until chomr says

```
test.com redirected you too many times.
```

what did i do wrong ?

also its such a weird issue when i do an ajax call.. it always gives me a 302 error..

[image]

Comment: You are missing a second `server` block. You are redirecting to a domain called `test.com`, so you need a `server` block with a `server_name` set to that domain. Everything from the `return` statement onwards needs to be in this second `server` block.

Comment: can you submit an answer ? kind of confused...